# How to access chrome.storage.sync outside extension in Vue app?

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing my extension's options page with Vue, but when I run the dev server, I am not in my extension and therefore can't access chrome.storage.sync. Is there any way to allow access?

Right now, I have to run `npm run build`, which places the static assets in my chrome extension's directory and takes almost 30 seconds, and refresh the extension in chrome to test changes.

Please let me know if I haven't provided enough info.

Comment: There's no way. Why is your build so slow? It should be 10 times faster.

Comment: oof idk im just using vue cli 3. I am on a new computer.

Comment: well i just went ahead and mimicked it so that I could test it

```
let chrome = {
  storage: {
    sync: {
      get(defaults, callback) {
        return callback(defaults);
      }
    }
  }
}
```